# Subprocess pipe breaks program

Tags: python, popen

I am automating a GUI application that also has a CLI. I can successfully run the following (theApplication is an internally developed app):

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(r'theApplication.exe -foo=7')
```

It then prints its output which I wish to process, so I use subprocess.PIPE

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(r'theApplication.exe -foo=7', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now the program does not start and Windows reports that `theApplication has stopped working`. The same happens if the stdout is redirected to DEVNULL or a file. I tried setting `bufsize` to 0 and 1 and the same happens.

Tried all permutations with `stdout` and `stderr` being redirected or not. It only works if neither of them is redirected. If one is redirected it instantly breaks the program. The value of `process.returncode` is `None`.

How can pipeing the output can break the program?

Comment: No, it's not a `subprocess` bug. `theApplication` must be doing something weird, like checking if its stdout is connected to a terminal or not.

Comment: How such a check could be fooled with subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried it with list parameter? Like:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["theApplication.exe", "-foo=7"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: I tried it just now, and it produces the same error.

Comment: Perhaps you should define stderr as PIPE as well and check it. Furthermore  you can check the return code of your command. Eg.: process.returncode. On the other hand I think the problem is in theApplication.exe not in subprocess.

Comment: Tried all permutations with stdout and stderr being redirected or not, does not matter. The returncode is `NoneType`. So definitly the process does not start. The question now is how pipeing can break the program.

Comment: Could you try the following implementation?
`import subprocess`
`process = subprocess.Popen(["theApplication.exe", "-foo=7"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) `
`out, err = process .communicate()`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to also redirect `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, altough the theApplication does not read from it.